# Help me to find a way to do this repetitive stuff

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation

I'm trying to do this:

```
p = 10;
a = ToString[N[Sqrt[3], p^2 - 1]];

a = Characters[a ];
b = Table[ToString[n], {n, 0, 9}];
n = 0; i = 0;
a = StringReplace[a, "." -> "g"];

a /. ToString[0] -> Graphics[{CMYKColor[1, 0, 0, 0], Rectangle[]}]
```

The idea is to replace the numbers, with a rectangle of each color - small numbers are brighter, bigger numbers are dark, the point is to be transformed in a green square.

But for doing this, I must repeat the code a lot:

```
    a /. 
ToString[0] -> Graphics[{CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 0], Rectangle[]}]  /. 
ToString[1] -> Graphics[{CMYKColor[1, 0, 0, 0], Rectangle[]}]  /. 
ToString[2] -> Graphics[{CMYKColor[2, 0, 0, 0], Rectangle[]}]  /. 
ToString[3] -> Graphics[{CMYKColor[3, 0, 0, 0], Rectangle[]}] ...
```

I tried to use Table, but it didn't work. I was trying the following:

```
Table[a /. ToString[o] -> Graphics[{CMYKColor[o, 0, 0, 0], Rectangle[]}], {0, 0, 9}]
```

But it didn't work. What would be a nice way to do this?

Comment: What about `g`? With what do you want to be replaced with?

Comment: The `g` is the point, I switched it because I couldn't make `/. ToString[.] -> Graphics[{CMYKColor[x/a1, x/10, 0, x/a3], Rectangle[]}]` work.

Comment: And what values `x,a1,a3` have?

Comment: Why do you convert to strings? And what are `b`, `n` for? I'd just use: `Graphics[{CMYKColor[#/10, 0, 0, 0], , Rectangle[]}, 
   ImageSize -> 25] & /@ RealDigits[Sqrt[3], 10, p^2 - 1][[1]]` or any other color scheme, as in @Spawn1701D 's answer... but I guess I am missing something

Comment: @PinguinDirk you have to make an exception for the `.` but apart from that this is the fastest solution.

Comment: I assumed he doesn't want the "." in the output (it's rather a relict from conversion to strings etc.) I'll post my comment as an answer if that's the case, let's wait for a reaction :)

Comment: `CMYKColor[]` clips its arguments to all lie within $[0,1]$, FYI.

Answer (score 4):

(Too long for a comment now)

looking at the question, I understand you want to take all digits (up to `p^2-1`) of a given number and map that to colors. Here's how I'd do it:

```
p=10;
```

and then, using `RealDigits`:

```
Graphics[{CMYKColor[#/9, 0, 0, 0], , Rectangle[]}, 
ImageSize -> 25] & /@ RealDigits[Sqrt[3], 10, p^2 - 1][[1]]
```

[image]

Note that this does not account for integer- or fractional parts. For that, one might split up the list accordingly or e.g. do:

```
Map[Graphics[{CMYKColor[#/9, 0, 0, 0], , Rectangle[]}, 
 ImageSize -> 
  25] &, #] & /@ (RealDigits /@ {IntegerPart@#, 
   FractionalPart@#} &@N[Sqrt[3], p^2 - 1])[[All, 1]]
```

to get first a list of the rectangles corresponding to the integer part and then, secondly, for the fractional part. From your question, I cannot see what you might want, thus I leave the output mostly **unformatted** as a list.

[image]

Using `Table` (based on the first approach), you could use:

```
Table[Graphics[{CMYKColor[i/9, 0, 0, 0], , Rectangle[]}, 
  ImageSize -> 25], {i, RealDigits[Sqrt[2], 10, p^2 - 1][[1]]}]
```

Also, see @Spawn1701D 's answer for the use of any other (fancy) colorscheme.

And, not to forget: maybe you'd like (your avatar suggests so...):

```
ArrayPlot[RealDigits[\[Pi], 10, p^2][[1]]~Partition~p, 
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Comment: note that I focused on the "repetitive" stuff and tried to give generic outputs that should allow to insert green squares where ever wanted, needed, desired. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Answering this specifically:

> The idea is to replace the numbers, 
>   with a rectangle of each color - 
>    **small numbers are brighter, bigger numbers are dark**, the point is to \
>   be transformed in a **green square**.

And borrowing the code from @Pinguin

```
p = 50;
ArrayPlot[RealDigits[\[Pi], 10, p^2][[1]]~Partition~p, 
          ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0, 1 - #, 0] &)]
```

[image]

```
p = 10;
s = Flatten@ConstantArray[Range[0, 9], p];
ArrayPlot[NestList[RotateLeft[#, 1] &, s, p p], 
          ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0, 1 - #, 0] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
a /. s : Except["g", _String] :> Graphics[{CMYKColor[ToExpression[s]/10, 0, 0, 0], 
                                          Rectangle[]}]
```

but this is a more colorful one:

```
a /. s : Except["g", _String] :> Graphics[{ColorData["Rainbow"][ToExpression[s]/10], 
                                          Rectangle[]}]
```

and if you want just green:

```
a /. s : Except["g", _String] :> Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 1 - ToExpression[s]/10, 0], 
                                           Rectangle[]}]
```

Comment: Check on the online help of Mathematica the command `ColorData` there a slew of different color schemes to choose from.

Comment: Also if you want to control the brightness `Hue` is better.